# Firebase Authentication using Phone - Recaptcha Verification - React JS - Uncaught runtime errors - Web

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I'm using Phone option of Firebase auth service. It requires recaptcha. I'm using invisible recaptcha. But facing some issue in it. When the recaptcha gets generated, after some time, it throws "Runtime error"

Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
Timeout
at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:126683:58)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:126706:7

Following is the code:

```
    async function generateRecaptcha() {
        try {
            if (recaptchaVerifier) {
                // Clear the previous reCAPTCHA instance
                recaptchaVerifier?.clear();
            }
        
            let recaptcha = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'sign-in-btn', {
                'size': 'invisible',
            });
        
            await recaptcha?.verify();
            setRecapchaVerifier(recaptcha);
            return recaptcha;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error generating reCAPTCHA:", error);
            setError("Recaptcha Verification Failed.");
            return undefined;
        }
    }
```

And in my login function I am calling this function as below:

```
    try{
        setAuthenticating(true);
        const recaptcha = await generateRecaptcha();
        setRecapchaVerifier(recaptcha);
        if(recaptcha != undefined){
            const firebaseConfirmation = await authService.sendOTP(phone, recaptcha);
            setConfirmationResult(firebaseConfirmation);
            setCodeSent(true);
        }else{
            setError("Recaptcha Verification Failed.");
        }
    }catch(error: any){
        setError('Firebase Authentication error.');
    }
```

What can be the reason for this? Any guidance will be much appreciated.